# Transformer fuse for primary coil. 240V with 16VA

Tags: power, transformer, ac, power-electronics, fuses

So I know it may be a basic question but hear me out. [These are the specs](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/0f46/0900766b80f46e63.pdf) for the transformer I would like to buy.

To add a fuse to the primary coil I would do 16VA/240V which gives 0.06A. Does that mean I need to get a 100mA fuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Does that mean I need to get a 100mA fuse?*

Yes, a 100 mA fuse should do the job.

There are fast (F) and slow (T) fuses, I would start with a fast fuse and see how that works out. If the fuse would sometimes blow when the transformer is connected to AC mains then try again with a slow fuse.

Comment: Thank you Bimpelrekkie. Should this be the correct one? Does it correspond to the specification of the transformer? https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/cartridge-fuses/0563582/

Comment: There is no need to have the fuse "*correspond to the specification of the transformer*". A fuse is a fuse. This is a **slow** fuse. It will do the job.

Comment: Okay that's great so that it will work fine then? Should I order it?

Comment: @M2T156 It will work just fine. Make sure you have a proper fuse holder. Keep in mind that transformers tend to draw large amounts of current for 3-4 grid periods, when connected. So if the fuse blows, just buy a 200 mA fuse.

Comment: The fuse has a current of 35A is that you are talking about the surge current?

Comment: *The fuse has a current of 35A* Beware that that is the **guaranteed interruption current** which means that as long as the current through the fuse is 35 A or less, this fuse is **guaranteed** to blow and interrupt the current. You can't for example expect this fuse to be able to interrupt a 1000 A current, it is too small for that. In practice you do not need to worry much about this interruption current. For a good explanation about fuses, watch BigClive's video about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kx35WN3uLis&t=3s

Comment: Okay I understand about that. So it has not got to do with the surge 3 - 4 period. Is this a good holder? https://fr.rs-online.com/web/p/products/1769047/